# generic wrapper or JS plug-in to parse another HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, d3.js

what to write a generic wrapper or JS plug-in, 
which read parse giving HTML (separate html) and find Tables within HTML files and allow user to generate visual graphs like pie,bar etc
Challenge: HTML structure is not fix, it may contain TABLE or not, there is chances of nested tables

Any suggetion about approach, open to use any JS frameworks

what to write a generic wrapper or JS plug-in, 
which read parse giving HTML (separate html) and find Tables within HTML files and allow user to generate visual graphs like pie,bar etc
Challenge: HTML structure is not fix, it may contain TABLE or not, there is chances of nested tables

Any suggetion about approach, open to use any JS frameworks

Idea is, giving option to user to generate visual representation on existing html which regenerating them

```
thinking something list this...
folder contains multiple html files for example
report-1.html -> contains 2 tables
report-2.html -> contains 1 tables
report-3.html -> contains 3 tables


MainWrapperHTML.html -> ajax call to folder and list all HTML
                    -> user can select one html file (report html file, for example user selected report-1.html)
                    -> this selected HTML file will become source file
                    -> Javascript need to parse this report-1.html and show tables and let user to pick table
                    -> some more steps......
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I don't fully get what you want to achieve, it's not really clear.

If you want to use Javascript though to parse an HTML DOM and then modify it you could use the [htmlparser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmlparser2) plugin to get the DOM and then modify it using vanilla Javascript.